# queuing system that allows you to dequeue multiple items at once

Tags: queuing

I'm wondering if there is a queuing system that allows one to dequeue multiple items at once. A quick google search turned up oracle's Advanced Queuing, but the use case doesn't warrant anything as crazy as getting oracle licenses. I'm pretty convinced there is no such system that is open source or at least not oracle expensive, but I thought i'd ask just in case. The goal behind this is to implement reliable batching of queued items, so if anyone has a suggestion on how to do it without writing your own application level implementation, that would be welcome.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to dequeue multiple items at onces (i.e. atomically ?). Why can't the batch processing system just dequeue as many items as it can handle before processing them ?